# How to remove only (blank) in pivot table VB script?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove the (blank) from my pivot table.
Problem is when I do that the next time I use the pivot table new items are not selected.

Is there a solution to this?
One possible solution would be to refresh the pivot table->

1. Select all items
2. remove blank

Here's the code I use to remove blanks

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Campaign")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best practice is to create an Excel table to store your data.

- Select all of you data.
- Press Home tab, Style group & Format as table.
- Now enter a new line. Table will automatically expand and catch the new line.
- Then modify pivot table source to use the new table by pressing anywhere in the Pivot Table area, Analyze tab, Data tab - Change Data Source & type the table name instead of a range.
- Now use the below code

  ```
  Sub Macro1()

   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6")
       .RefreshTable
       With .PivotFields("Campaign")
           .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
           .CurrentPage = "(All)"
           .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
       End With
   End With

  End Sub
  ```